# strange complex function call using angle braket

Tags: javascript, brackets

I was reading some basics about javascript here:

http://javascript.info/tutorial/array
And I was struck by the following paragraph:

"Note how JavaScript allows complex syntax like: reverse()[0] - to call a method and then take an element of resulting array.

Actually, you can compose longer calls, like `reverse()<a href="/0%5D%5B1">0][1</a>[5]...,` language syntax allows that."

I tried to search online for such usage for the `function()<a` but I failed to find any guidance

My question is:

- Can we use the angle braket directly a after a function, not as part of string??
- Am I missing things here??

Comment: that is not javascript, there must be a typo in the info source.

Comment: It's a runaway HTML tag in the tutorial. It should read `reverse()[0][1][5]...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we use the angle braket directly a after a function, not as part of string??

Yes, but it will be the "less than" comparison operator. Valid example:

```
if (reverse() < 5) // this example assumes `reverse` returns something reasonably
                   // comparable with 5
```

This quoted example:

```
reverse()<a href="/0%5D%5B1">0][1</a>[5]...,
//          ^
```

...is quite definitely a syntax error as of the indicated location. Up until then it was calling `reverse` and then comparing the result with `a` (a variable), but then the space followed by `href` makes no sense.

Either the article is nonsense, or more likely the markup for it has gotten messed up.

**Edit**:

[Juhana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502381/juhana) points out in a comment that it's probably supposed to be

```
reverse()[0][1][5]
```

...which does this:

- Calls `reverse()`
- Applies `[0]` to the resulting value (so hopefully it's an array or an object with a property called `"0"`)
- Applies `[1]` to *that* resulting value
- Applies `[5]` to *that* resulting value

So for example:

```
function reverse() {
    return [             // Outermost array
        [                // First nested array
            [],          // First entry in nested array (not used)
            [            // Second entry in nested array
                'a',
                'b',
                'c',
                'd',
                'e',
                'f',     // Index 5 of the innermost array
                'g'
            ]
        ]
    ];
}

console.log(reverse()[0][1][5]); // "f"
```